# db.get() vs Model.get()

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

I have started working on the datastore and I found that we can get the instance(s) by this method get() which was available in db and in Model class. But what the difference between them I don't find it my questions are

```
1. how its working in background to get the Instance of an Model
2. how the performance wise of use db.get() and Model.get()
3. When use db.get() and Model.get()
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're effectively identical. They call the same RPC and have the same performance.

The only difference is that `Model.get` validates that the key matches the model's kind.

Comment: You can also use db.get() to retrieve a list of entities of different models.

Comment: @CanBascil Which is a direct consequence of the difference Drew mentions in his answer.